# The HTTP service located at "address" is too busy

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using WCF to continuously stream images from server to client. However, whenever I try to run it, I always get this error:

> The HTTP service located at "local host address here" is too busy.

I've looked everywhere on the web and tried others solutions. I've tried throttling, increasing the buffer sizes, and changing the transfer mode to no avail. I'm very new to WCF and don't know where else to go. If anyone has any idea how to get rid of this error, I would appreciate it. Thanks! Here is all my code.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_VisionWcfInterface" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="10"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8002/Visual/service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_VisionWcfInterface"
            contract="VisionWcfInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_VisionWcfInterface" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client.cs file and ClientWCF function:

```
public Form1()
{
    private VisionWcfClient client = new VisionWcfClient();
    client.Connect();
    pictureBox2.Image = ConvertByteArrayToImage(client.GetVideoStream());
}

public byte[] GetVideoStream()
{
    return m_clientProxy.GetVideoStream();
}
```

Server.cs file and ServerWCF function:

```
public byte[] GetVideoStream()
{
    return GetVideoStreamEvent();
}

byte[] ads_GetVideoStreamEvent()
{
    IntPtr pointer;

    m_Buffers.GetAddress(out pointer);

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(m_Buffers.Width, m_Buffers.Height, m_Buffers.Pitch, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, pointer);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette palette = b.Palette;
    Color[] entries = palette.Entries;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);

    b.Palette = palette;
    m_Buffers.ReleaseAddress(pointer);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. I changed the port number from 8002 to 8003 and it worked. Don't really know why but as long as it works, I don't care.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... The issue was that the account linked to the application pool in which my service was running had its password changed.

After associating the AppPool with a valid credential, the service began to run normally again.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are "continuously" streaming images, does that mean you are doing this in a loop?

---

Update:
I recommend that you turn on the WCF tracing to help determine the problem.  See this info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Also, what are the service attributes you have defined on your service method and interface?

Comment: Eventually I will be, but I am trying to get at least one image right now. Will I end up running into problems if I do?

Comment: No, I just noted the disparity between your description and the code, and was thinking that perhaps you had too many concurrent connections.  You will have to change the configuration to allow the number of simultaneous connections you want (I forget how many the default is) but that shouldn't be your problem here.

Comment: This is a very stupid question, but like I mentioned before, I'm new. So what do you mean by service headers?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Attributes" instead of headers.  Specifically what do you have set for the [ServiceContract()] and [OperationContract()] on your service class/method?
See here:  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx)